# Unity2D, How to change the diameter of the spinning object towards the centre point

Tags: unity-game-engine

im new in unity and I'm making a simple game, a kind of earth that is orbiting the sun, this earth is rotating using RotateAround(), I want to change the diameter of the earth to the sun based on user input, so the earth can be farther or closer to the sun,but it still orbiting to the sun. I can't program it .
Here's the code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 100;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    float movement;


    void Update()
    {
        movement = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.RotateAround(new Vector3(movement,0,0), Vector3.forward,  Time.fixedDeltaTime * -speed);
    }
```

all kinds of help mean a lot to me.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: change the scale on x,y,z to keep it the same proportions

Answer (score 0):

RotateAround won't work very well in your situation.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

You can take a simple approach, which is to put the Earth inside an empty GameObject, then rotate the empty and move the Earth over its local position to make it orbit farther or closer. The pivot center of the empty should be the same position as the sun.

The hard way is to use math. Basically define a distance and then calculate its x and z (y in 2D) position based on the Sin and Cos of the angle, which you should increase over the time. But since you are new, I advise you the first one.